# Responsive View Problem Form Elements on Mobile

Tags: html, css, forms, responsive-design

My Website has a problem on mobile view.  when i click to input fields for writing somethings, Form size changing... how can i fixed it?  I add to form background (css- **resize:none**; but its not worked. )
You can see here!
[Screen View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpdOx.jpg)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is - depending height of a block **.formular-bg** . When the keyboard in On - the viewport height changes although. 85**hv** - it depends on viewport height, which is changes dramatically when keyboard appears.

```
.formular-bg {
    background: rgba(255, 254, 254, 0.93);
    width: 100%;
    height: 60vh; /*make it 'auto' or remove*/
    float: right;
    margin-top: 10%;
    resize: none; /*it's not going to work with fixed height*/
}
```

And this one

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
.formular-bg {
    background: rgb(248, 248, 248,0.9);
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20%;
    margin-left: 5%;
    text-align: center;
    height: 85vh;/*make it 'auto' or remove*/
    resize: none;
}
}
```